# Convention in cats: where to declare typeclasses instances

Tags: scala, typeclass, scala-cats

Assume you have some class `A` and you want to declare an instance of some typeclass `T` for `A`. Where the instance declaration should be placed? Personally I would put it in the companion object of class `A`. For instance, if I would be declaring an instance for Monoid, I would write it like this:

```
class A

object A {
    implicit def monoidInstance = new Monoid[A] {
         override def empty = ???
         override def combine ... 
    } 
}
```

However I couldn't find any conventions on this matter. Are there better or recommended ways?

Comment: I don't think there is a convention as this really depends on each project, but my usual approach matches yours. If the typeclass instance is something that I think would be used often, IMO the companion object is a good place for it.

Comment: My rule of thumb is that it should go in the companion object whenever it can. If it can't (because the dependency providing the type class isn't available there, for example), I'd put the instance together with any related instances in a trait and provide an object extending that trait for convenience.